# Can't read HDD partitions from Live USB

Tags: filesystem, boot-partition

Hi got a problem with Linux today.

At boot show a message:

`fsckd-cancel-msg: Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress`

And stay stuck.

Trying to access the HDD from another Live USB  to rescue the files, but when plug and mount the HDD, it only shows a grub folder with the an initrd.img and an vmlinuz and not much more.

Where are the other partitions: Home, usr, etc?

Before mounted from grub the linux kernel to boot manually, maybe is because not mounted manually the other partitions and now stay like that? *(Got various LVM partitions)*

The tutorial I followed for mount and boot manually was that was that
: https://www.unix-ninja.com/p/Manually_booting_the_Linux_kernel_from_GRUB

Now while use `ls` on grub CLI it shows:

- (lvm/myLVM-homeLVM)
- (lvm/myLVM-varLVM)
- (lvm/myLVM-usrLVM)
- (lvm/myLVM-swapLVM)
- (lvm/myLVM-rootLVM)
- (lvm/myLVM-var_tmpLVM)
- (lvm/myLVM-tmpLVM)
- (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)

What must to do?

*(the only want to do rightnow is get access to my /home to save all the stuff and re-install it with a less complicated partition setup)*

Hope all the stuff still there.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Please, if can tell me just how to mount all the partitions from grub CLI I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me this question is mostly asking how to properly mount partitions? (If this is not what you are asking, I apologize and request you try rephrasing your question to be more precise.)

If so, first you need to find what disks and partitions are present. Do this by running `lsblk`. This will give you a list. Look in this list for entries that say "part" under `TYPE`. These are the available partitions for you to mount. Find the partition you want to mount. In this example I will say it is `sdb2`, though it will have a different name for you.

After you have the partition you want to mount identified, you are going to need to find or make a folder as the mount location. This can be done with `sudo mkdir /mnt/MountFolderName` where MountFolderName is the name of the folder you want to create.

Next, mount the partition at the location of the folder you just created. Do this with `sudo mount /dev/sdb2/ /mnt/MountFolderName/`

Once you have mounted it, you should be able to navigate to the folder `/mnt/MountFolderName/` and find the file contents of the partition.

There are lost of ways this could get complicated (e.g. It needs to be mounted as NTFS or some other file system, or it needs special permissions, etc.). If this is the case, you need to look into the options for the `mount` command.

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of the HDD? Was it formatted on Windows? If so, you may need to `sudo apt-get install exfat-utils`

`sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse` also if fuse doesn't also install automatically. It looks like you are formatted to msdos which is Windows